# Prove that either $a_1 =0$ or $a_2 =0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, solution-verification

I was having a look at this question

> Let $f$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Define $a_1 = f(0);~~a_2= f(a_1) = f(f(0))$ and $a_n = f(a_{n-1})$ for $n \geq 3$. If there exists a natural number $k \geq 3$ such that $a_k = 0$, then prove that either $a_1 = 0$ or $a_2= 0$
>
> Source: [ISI B-MATH UGB 2019 paper](https://librarykv2calicut.files.wordpress.com/2020/02/bmath-ugb-2019-1.pdf)

And at first glance I couldn't understand whether $a_i$'s were the coefficients of the given polynomial or they are some separate sequence. After some time I came to the conclusion that the latter is correct. I have tried to prove it, but in need of some validation so as to confirm if my proof is free from flaws. The solution which I have done is quite long, so if it makes the question hard to read then please let me know in the comments and  I shall post it as answer. Any other answer with some different idea is also welcome (but it has to be a full solution).

---

Let $k$ be the least number such that $a_k = 0$ in the sequence $a_1, a_2 , a_3 \cdots $.
$a_k = 0 \implies P(a_k) = P(0) = a_1$
$P(a_{k-1}) = a_k \implies P(a_{k-1}) = 0$
As $P(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, therefore $P(0)$ will be an integer and hence $a_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

By the same argument, $P(a_1) = a_2 \in \mathbb{Z}, P(a_2) = a_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$, that is $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

It is a well know theorem that if $P(x)$ is  a polynomial with integer coefficients, then if $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ implies $ (a-b) \big| \left(P(a)- P(b)\right)$.

Applying the above theorem continuously
$$
a_1 \big| P(a_1)- P(0) \implies a_1 \big| a_2 - a_1 \implies |a_1| \leq |a_2 - a_1 | $$
$$a_2 - a_1 \big| P(a_2) - P(a_1) \implies a_2 -a_1 \big| a_3 -a_2 \implies |a_2 -a_1 | \leq |a_3 - a_2| $$
$$\cdots $$
$$a_ k - a_{k-1} \big| P(a_k) - P(a_{k-1}) \implies (-a_{k-1}) \big| a_1 \implies|a_{k-1}| \leq |a_1| $$

$$|a_1 | \leq |a_2 -a_1 | \leq |a_3 - a_2| \leq \cdots \leq |a_{k-1}| \leq |a_1| $$
As, $|a_{k-1}|$ is greater than/equal to and less than/equal to $|a_1|$ therefore, to avoid contradiction we have to have
$$
|a_1| = |a_2 -a_1| = |a_3 - a_2| \cdots = |a_{k-1}|$$

We notice that if in above it ever happens that $a_i - a_{i-1} = - \left( a_{i+1} - a_{i}\right)$ then we will get :
$$
a_i - a_{i-1} = a_i - a_{i+1}  $$
$$a_{i-1} = a_{i+1} $$
$$ P (a_{i-1}) = P(a_{i+1}) \implies a_i = a_{i+2} $$
$$ P(a_i)= P(a_{i+2}) \implies a_{i+1} = a_{i+3} $$
And the process continues until we get $a_k = 0$ which would mean that either $a_{i-1}$ is zero or $a_{i}$ is zero and hence $k$ will no longer be the least number such that $a_k = 0$. Therefore, to avoid contradiction we have to have
$$
|a_1| = a_2 - a_1 = a_3 - a_2 = a_4 - a_3 \cdots = |a_{k-1}| $$
If $ -a _1 = a_2 - a_1$ then $a_2= 0$.
If $a_1 = a_2 - a_1$ then we have $ a_2 = 2a_1$
$$a_2 - a_1 = a_3 - a_2 \implies a_3 = 3 a_1 $$
Similarly, $a_4 = 4 a_1$, $ a_5 = 5 a_1$ and so on. That means, the absolute values of the terms are increasing and hence there is no chance that there will be a $k$ such that $a_k = 0$ until and unless $a_1$ is itself zero.

Comment: Note: Right after the modulus inequality, the OP has started to do case work (Though they haven't mentioned they are)

Comment: This question has been answered in Theorem 2 of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.06760.

Answer (score 4):

There are some concerning steps, but nothing is particularly difficult to address.

- You've used $a \mid b \implies |a| \leq |b|$ several times, but this is incorrect.  The corrected implication is $a \mid b \implies (|a| \leq |b| \text{ or } b=0).$  In context, however, this other case relates to the possibility that $a_i = a_{i+1}$ for some $i$, and you've addressed a similar issue later from $a_{i-1}=a_{i+1}$.
- Most of your proof follows the pattern of "Case 1, Case 2, ..., Case k" which can sometimes hide problems for small $k$-values.  For instance, when $k=1$, what does $$|a_1 | \leq |a_2 -a_1 | \leq |a_3 - a_2| \leq \cdots \leq |a_{k-1}| \leq |a_1|$$ even say?  And if that sequence of inequalities doesn't exist, can you really argue as you do later?  This, of course, can be ignored if you assume, towards a contradiction, that $k \geq 3$ at the onset.
- It is incorrect to write $|a_1| = a_2 - a_1$ as in $$|a_1| = a_2 - a_1 = a_3 - a_2 = a_4 - a_3 =\cdots = |a_{k-1}|$$ but you never actually use $|a_1| = a_2-a_1$ in your proof.  Rather, you use the correct $|a_1| = |a_2-a_1|$.

Comment: Thanks, I like pedantic reviews. That $k geq 3$ was given in the question so I thought of not making it explicit.

Comment: @Knight As written, the $k$ in the question and your $k$ cannot be the same (this is what you end up proving), so if you want your $k$ to satisfy $k \geq 3$, you actually do need to write that as an assumption.